# How to remove the border line for the header in the expander control in silverlight 3?

Tags: silverlight, expander

Please suggest a right answer

Answer (score 0):

Edit the style for the header or edit a copy of the control template. Go research keywords: "style" and "control template".

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the control in Expression Blend.  Click "Edit template" and then click "Edit Copy".

Give the "Style Resource" a name.

Under "Objects and Timeline", select the header and make changes to its style.

Answer (score 0):

AS said above when code is generated then replace StrokeThickness="1" by StrokeThickness="0"

you will get the line removed

< Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" Stroke="#FF448DCA" StrokeThickness="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" Visibility="Collapsed" />